# Parsing XML Excel workbook in Coldfusion

Tags: xml, excel, coldfusion, xml-parsing

I have a large XML Excel. I need to parse it to read the rows in it. A sample XML Excel with exact tags can be seen at [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/461-creating-microsoft-excel-documents-with-coldfusion-and-xml.htm).

The link explains how to create but could not find how to read it.

Following is what I have tried so far.

```
<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "90000"><!---File is too large --->
<cffile action="read" file="#ExpandPath("./myxml.xml")#" variable="myxml" />
<cfset mydoc = XmlParse(myxml) />
<cfdump var="#mydoc#" /><!---Dumping displays the XML content--->
<cfset recordNodes = xmlSearch( mydoc, "Workbook" ) />
<cfdump var="#ArrayLen(recordNodes)#"><!---should display number of occurrences of Workbook tag--->
```

I am trying to read the XPATH, but the first tag itself is not found. No error. Above code is giving be 0 instead of 1.

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Pretty sure that this is a namespace problem. See http://www.aftergeek.com/2006/08/xmlsearch-xpath-and-xml-namespaces-in.html. So try `xmlSearch( mydoc, "//*[local-name()='Workbook']" )`or `xmlSearch( mydoc, "//*:Workbook" )`

Comment: this works. Thanks you. But how can I look for row tags with xpath('Workbook/Worksheet/Table/Row') or can I simply replace Workbook tag with Row in xmlSearch function?

Comment: @AxelRichter: Can you move your comment to answer so that I can mark it as answered. And Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Hm, I've no experience with coldfusion. So maybe someone other will answer better. Seems as if coldfusion is not able providing a prefix-namespace mapping for its XPATH, see http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html. But this would be the best solution since you otherwise always must write the ugly any-namespace-syntax in your XPATH. But http://www.coldfusionguy.com/ColdFusion/blog/index.cfm/2008/9/26/XMLSearch-Specify-xmlns-namespaces-in-an-xPath-Search looks as if you must.

Comment: By XML Excel, are you talking about a .xlsx file?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: No, Excel 2003 Spreadsheet XML, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example. See also the link in the Question.